# How to sync google drive folders w/ slack workspaces?

Tags: automation, google-drive, slack, integration

Which app/service will sync a specified folder (e.g., "slack") from my Google Drive w/ my Slack workspaces in a way similar to...

```
slack
    1workspace
        general
            member-a
            member-b
        random
            member-a
            member-b
        channel-a
            member-a
    2workspace
        general
            member-b
            member-c
        random
            member-b
            member-c
        channel-b
            member-c
        channel-c
            member-b
            member-c
```

Following these simple rules...

1. Update workspace folders whenever 1 is added/removed.
2. Update channel folders whenever 1 is added/removed.
3. Update member folders whenever 1 is added/removed to/from a workspace or channel.
4. Whenever a new member is added to a workspace, give them access to (organize, add, & edit) the respective drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cover most of your use cases using Zapier, and its [Google Drive to Slack integration](https://zapier.com/apps/google-drive/integrations/slack).

I believe you will have to set up each workspace independently, so whatever setup you do for one workspace you will have to replicate it for the others.

There is a trigger for whenever a file is added/removed and that could generate an action like posting a new message to a channel.

There is also a trigger for whenever a new Slack User is created, which could trigger the action for *Change File Sharing Preference*
(But I do not think you will be able to achieve number 4 for a channel level out of the box unless zapier adds a new trigger)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried Zapier but the "Change File Sharing Preference" action was exactly that. It didn't give the option to share access with a specific user.

Comment: Then, since it looks like your only chance might just be to use slack's hooks and Google Drive API.
You could try using zapier for as much as you can, and then check:
[Google Drive API, Manage Sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)

[Slack Incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)

[Slack Outgoing webhooks](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks)